# Remove asymmetrical buzzing sound from an audio

Tags: editing, noise, post-production, audio-editor

I'm trying to remove a buzzing sound from a recorded audio using [Audacity](http://web.audacityteam.org/). The sound happens to be not easy to remove using the built-in Noice Reduction filter because it's asymmetrical. Is there any easy way to remove it? Or is it even practically possible?

- Screenshot of Audacity displaying the noice:
  [image: Screenshot of Audacity displaying the noice]
- [Audio sample](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66084682/buzzing%20sound%20sample.mp3)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter about what is asymmetrical. Sometimes you can't rely on the Waveform alone.

Looking at a Spectrum (see image, taken from an unspoken part), you can see that there are loud, bands of high frequency interference. The inteference is constant, and probably from a Fridge or electronic device. The frequencies are so loud that it may be best just using a Low pass filter to remove all above 2khz!

If you have access to iZotope RX, you can attentuate large bands of frequencies piece by piece, but in your case the recording quality is already significantly bad and may not be worth the time.

[image: Spectrum]

Comment: Hey, that was helpful! It's probably due to my inexperience in advanced audio editing that I should have checked frequency spectrum before asking the question, but others might find it helpful as well. I've removed the buzzing noise using the Low Pass Filter. It has made the voice sound a bit worse but, of course, overall it sounds a lot better. Thank you. :)

Comment: Cool! There is a bit of sibilance in that area as well and while most of it becomes distorted, those parts still contribute to our understanding of the speech! Do you know how this was recorded?

Comment: I know, I know. This was recorded by me and my friends for the project I'm working on as a part-time job (I'm a student). It was recorded with a microphone that I removed from a broken headphones. My friend bought a microphone, but its quality turned out to be even worse, so we used the other one. Though, I don't know where did this sound come from. It starts at some point in the audio and lasts till the end, but in the next recording we did after a half an hour after this, there is no such sound. We'll definitely get a much better microphone for the future recordings.